# Make a List from a DB varchar data - NetBeans + Derby

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, derby, jlist

my problems is that i dont know how to make a list (Jlist from NetBeans) with some data from my derby db

EX:

I have a form that saves the id,name,phone and email from a "client", and i want to show all the names from my previously registered clients in a list, the problem is that i need to convert the varchar data into a listmodel. How can i do that? I tried this, but didn't work:

```
    while (rs.next()){
        int id_col = rs.getInt("clientID");
        String name = rs.getString("clientName");

        client_listClients.setText(name);       
    }
```

It says that "couldn't find symbol" for .setText

**EDIT** using `DefaultListModel`

WORKING RESULT!

```
public void DoConnect( ) {

    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    client_listClients.setModel(model);

    try {
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ANAIA_DB";
        String uName = "*****";    
        String uPass = "*****";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM APP.CLIENT";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


        while (rs.next()){

            int id_col = rs.getInt("clientID");       
            String name = rs.getString("clientName");
            model.addElement(name);
        }
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.this, err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Thx aloooot @peeskillet

Comment: what is the datatype of client_listClients?

Comment: Now you should accept @peeskillet Answer ! **Tipp:** You should fill the model with values ​​and assign at the end to the list. This eliminates the need for each new element, the list to be redrawn. Put `client_listClients.setModel(model);` after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

> "It says that "couldant find symbol" for .setText"

`JList` *has* no method `setText()`. When in doubt, read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)

Instead, you'll want to use a `ListModel`. If you don't want to create your own, you can use the provided [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) implementation. There you have the method `addElement`.

You first need to declare your your list with the model.

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList client_listClients = new JList(model);
```

Then you can use the method `addElement`, which will automatically update the UI after all additions are made. No need to do anything with the list.

```
while (rs.next()){

    String name = rs.getString("clientName");
    model.addElement(name);

}
```

You can see more at [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), and focus on the section [Creating a Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating)

Comment: Thx for fast answer, but didnt work here.. my point is to get all names from db and make a list of it. I did this but the names arent showing on my client_listClients (Jlist)

Comment: It should work if you're doing it right. Please show the code you've tried so I can review it.

Comment: So I think the problem is that you have an existing JList? Am I correct? Then you create another JList in this method. Instead of creating a new JList (take that out), do `client_listClients.setModel(model)`